# Regarding goal-seek or fsolve (matlab) alike function in VBA

Tags: vba

I have been struggling for a while to try and implement a goal-seek function in VBA, but with no results, which is why I am turning to you guys.

I have a Variant of double-values, where the last element is just a temporary set value, which would have to be changed (as in goalseek) so that the sum of the entire array equals to 1. Of course this is exactly what you would do in a worksheet, but I need it in VBA, handling NO cells...

Is there a way to call the Goalseek function in VBA without having to use a worksheet (or cells), and instead just working with variables?

Thanks,
Niklas

Comment: this question, as it stands, it is out of scope for stackoverflow. please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and edit your question before it gets put on hold.

Comment: hope that clarifies things a bit...

Comment: http://excel.kingofmath.com/?p=267

Answer (score 0):

If it's only about filling the last array item then this code might come in handy:

```
Sub FillLastElementWithDifferenceToOne()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, sum As Double

    ReDim arr(1 To 10)

    'Fill Array with .01 - .09
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = i / 100
    Next i

    'Calculate sum = .45
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        sum = sum + arr(i)
    Next i

    'Set last item of array
    arr(UBound(arr)) = 1 - sum

    'Clean up
    Set arr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Otherwise please specify what exactly you want to accomplish with VBA and where the problems are and post the code where the problems occur.